# Remove Empty Heading (H1, H2, etc) That Might Contain Empty Span Tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've been banging my head on this one. I'm not an expert in regular expression and would really appreciate some help here.  I'm looking to remove empty tags that were left over from a content management editor and replace it with a break tag using PHP.

BEFORE:

```
<h3 _mce_style="text-align: center;" style="text-align: center;" class="cali"></h3>
<h3 _mce_style="text-align: center;" style="text-align: center;" class="cali"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" _mce_style="color: #000000;"> </span></h3>
```

AFTER:

```
<br />
<br />
```

I've come up with the following, its close...

```
<h([1-6]).*?>(.*?)<\/h[1-6]>
```

Comment: You may use this regex [**`<h(\d)\b[^>]*>(\s*<span[^>]*>\s*(?2)*<\/span>\s*+)*<\/h\1>`**](https://regex101.com/r/6jGnMO/1) however I'll add a more proper way using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. DOMDocument isn't available in the environment I'm working in, unfortunately.